# appendMessageOperation fails when the message size is bigger?

Tags: swift, mailcore2

I want to copy the sent message to **Sent** folder using `appendMessageOperation`.

When the message size is smaller(about below 3KB?) the operation finishes successfully.
But If the message is bigger, the operation gets timeout with error.

> Error Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=1 "A stable connection to the server could not be established." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=A stable connection to the server could not be established.}

Is there any limitation about appending a message?

**Environment**: iPhone/ios12, iCloud

Answer (score 0):

It's just because of my mistake.
The instance seems to be destroyed while appendMessageOperation is working...